# ArchLinux: Wifi-Menu and installing Dialog

Tags: arch-linux

I have followed the instructions at 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide
when installing ArchLinux on an older computer.

I have no wired connections available and the installation was done using Wifi. However when I try to start the wifi-menu after the installation I'm prompted about the Dialog package. Of course I can't install it without internet connection (I can't even use pacman -Sy).

I reboot and use the CD. When I want to install the dialog package it says it's already installed. I install it anyway and when I reboot the computer has no idea what I'm on about when I try to launch wifi-menu; it asks for the Dialog package again - that needs to be downloaded.

How do you get out of this Catch21 situation?

Comment: when you boot back in using the CD are you using `arch-chroot ` to get back inside your locally installed environment? otherwise you're inside the environment of the installation media

Comment: I am using arch-chroot. However now that you mention it, I have no idea if I'm "chrooting" to the right place. How would you check that? I'm inside the \mnt directory if that clears anything up.

Comment: Be sure that you've mounted your partition(s) and that you are `arch-chroot`ing into the correct place. When you chroot in, does your filesystem look correct ? If you've installed along with (or similar to) the beginners guide your command will look something similar to `arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash` though the second arg is just to set your shell

Comment: Trying arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash.

Comment: Sam, you are the best! It works now.

Comment: great, I added that as an answer so you can mark this question off as answered .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that you've mounted your partition(s) and that you are `arch-chroot`ing into the correct place. When you chroot in, does your filesystem look correct ? If you've installed along with (or similar to) the beginners guide your command will look something similar to `arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash` though the second arg is just to set your shell.